# Powershell 'Get-AzureRmMetric' not returning any data

Tags: powershell, azure, metrics

I'm trying to use `Get-AzureRmMetric` to return some metrics pertaining to one of my resources.

To do this I'm using the following code, but the cmdlet is not outputting any metrics.

```
$resourceId = "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/$resourceType/$resourceName"
Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId $resourceId -StartTime (get-date).AddHours(-2) -EndTime (get-date).AddHours(-1) -TimeGrain "01:00:00"
```

I've changed each of the variables used to construct the `$resourceId`, and as expected `Get-AzureRmMetric` throws an error.  This suggests that the I'm passing a valid resource Id to the cmdlet.

In addition, I've captured the results of `Get-AzureRmMetric` and checked it's `count` property, which was `0`.  To me it seems as though I'm giving the cmdlet everything it needs, but it's just not working as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/get-azurermmetric?view=azurermps-4.3.1).

What can I do to get the metrics that I require?

## Full Code

```
try
{
    $credtials = Get-AzureCredtials -AppId $AppId -AppSecretKey $AppSecretKey
    Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credtials -TenantId $tenantId -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

    $resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $resourceName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ResourceType $resourceType
    $resourceId = $resource.ResourceId

    Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId $resourceId -TimeGrain '01:00:00' -StartTime (get-date).AddHours(-2) -EndTime (get-date).AddHours(-1) -MetricNames 'INTERR'
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "[ERROR] $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
    exit 1
}
```

---

## Update

As of today, I'm seeing a message regarding deprecation when using `Get-AzureRmMetric`.

> WARNING: API deprecation: The use of the legacy metrics API will be discontinued in the next release. This implies a change in the call and the output of this cmdlet.

And here is exactly what I'm seeing in PowerShell.

[image]

Comment: not sure which metric you are after but I had to make sure I was in the correct sub with set-rmcontext then I used the following after my resource id:  -TimeGrain (new-timespan -Minutes 1) -MetricNames 'CpuPercentage

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the TimeGrain be less than the difference between StartTime and EndTime?

Comment: The difference is one hour, as is the TimeGrain.  I've tried shortening it just in case, but sadly that's not the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of the AzureRM module?

I ask because I don't see you passing any metrics in your command and you should be getting prompted to provide the metric name you want to retrieve.

Comment: Yep, using the latest version.  The 'Metrics' parameter is optional, and according to the docs all are returned if none are specified.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
-StartTime (get-date).AddHours(-2)
```

Have you checked the Azure resource ID was running at that time? And have you check that resource had enabled metrics?

Here are my scripts, and this work for me, please check it:

```
$id = '/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/jasontest1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/jasonvm'
$st = (get-date).addhours(-1)
$et = (get-date)
$timeg = '01:00:00'
$data = Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId $id -TimeGrain $timeg -StartTime $st -EndTime $et -MetricNames 'Percentage CPU'
```

result like this:

[image]

---

**Update2**:

The command work for Azure Powershell version 3.4.0.

We can use this script to get the information about your Azure PowerShell：

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

> WARNING: API deprecation: The use of the legacy metrics API will be
>   discontinued in the next release. This implies a change in the call
>   and the output of this cmdlet. Here is the PowerShell output:

[image]

More information about it, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258409/unable-to-access-guest-metrics-using-get-azurermmetric/46274028#46274028).

Comment: Yep, the resources were available.  I'm querying metrics from the likes of EventHubs and Function Apps, which return metrics via HTTP.  Thanks.

Comment: We can use `(Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition -ResourceId $id).name` to list available metrics, then use the metric name to get the value. Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258409/unable-to-access-guest-metrics-using-get-azurermmetric/46274028#46274028)

Comment: @DavidGard Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: @DavidGard Which version of your PowerShell? we can use this script to check it `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`, different version use different API, so we should check it first.

Comment: I'm also unable to obtain a result from `Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition`.  I'm using PowerShell version 5.1.14393.1715.  I've been looking at this again today and have noticed that a message about Deprecation is now being displayed (see my question update).  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGard Yes, that command work for Azure PowerShell version 3.4.0. we can use powershell script `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` to get your Azure powershell version. I will update my answer, please check it.

Comment: I'm Azure PowerShell using version 3.5.0.  Can I assume then that the only way to get the metrics that I require is to use the REST API?  I already have a script to do this, but was looking to use `Get-AzureRmMetric` as it's far more graceful.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGard Yes, for now, we should use REST API to get the metrics (guest). As we know, powershell use REST API too:)

Comment: @DavidGard Could you please share your script to me:)

Comment: My full script is in my question, less the values of variables that I cannot share for obvious reasons. Thanks.

Comment: ??? But there isn't an answer...  You say "for now we can use PowerShell version 3.5 to use that command", but that doesn't seem to be the - `Get-AzureRmMetric` doesn't retrun any results.

Comment: @DavidGard sorry for my mistake, could you please try to use 3.4?

Comment: At this time I'm not sure.  I intend to use this solution within an Azure Function, so it entirly depends on the version of the module that Function Apps employ.  Thanks.