# Unable to Access [Guest] metrics using Get-AzureRmMetric

Tags: powershell, azure, metrics, azure-powershell

I have guest-level metrics enable for an Azure Virtual Machine and am trying to get the history for the **[Guest]\Memory\Committed Bytes** property using `Get-AzureRMMetric`.

```
$endTime = Get-Date
$startTime = $endTime.AddMinutes(-540)
$timeGrain = '00:05:00'
$metricName = '\Memory\Committed Bytes'


$history=(Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId $resourceId `
-TimeGrain $timeGrain -StartTime $startTime `
-EndTime $endTime `
-MetricNames $metricName)

$history.data | Format-table -wrap Average,Timestamp,Maxiumim,Minimum,Total
```

I get the following error:
[image]

This code works fine if I change the `$metricname` to any of the host metrics ("Percentage CPU" for example), but I need to get the memory information.

Note:  This is in PowerShell 5.1, I've found that I can use almost the same code (`$history.metricvalues` rather than `$history.data`) in PowerShell v3 and I can get to the **[Guest]** metrics there, but not any of the host metrics.

[Powershell v3 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT5HN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

For now, Azure PowerShell does **not** support to use `Get-AzureRmMetric` to get `memory usage` metrics.

We can use `Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition` to get the supported metrics:

Here are the metrics for Azure VM:

```
PS D:\testdata> (Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition -ResourceId $id).name

Value                     LocalizedValue
-----                     --------------
Percentage CPU            Percentage CPU
Network In                Network In
Network Out               Network Out
Disk Read Bytes           Disk Read Bytes
Disk Write Bytes          Disk Write Bytes
Disk Read Operations/Sec  Disk Read Operations/Sec
Disk Write Operations/Sec Disk Write Operations/Sec
CPU Credits Remaining     CPU Credits Remaining
CPU Credits Consumed      CPU Credits Consumed
```

About supported metrics of Azure VM, please refer to this official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftcomputevirtualmachines).

Then we can use the value to get other metrics:

```
Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId $id -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -DetailedOutput -MetricNames "Network in"
```

Here is my PowerShell output:

[image]

As a workaround, we can use OMS to get the Memory usage, more information about configuring performance counters on OMS, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-sources-performance-counters).

---

**Update**:

You are right, we can run this command on Azure PowerShell version 3.4.0, it works fine.

When we run this command on Version 3.4.0, we will get this warning:

> WARNING: API deprecation: The use of the legacy metrics API will be
>   discontinued in the next release. This implies a change in the call
>   and the output of this cmdlet.
>   Here is the PowerShell output:
>   [image]

As a workaround, we can via the REST API to export metrics, more information about it, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-metrics#access-metrics-via-the-rest-api).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm not sure I understand why I am able to get the \Memory\Committed Bytes Guest metric in Powershell v3 using Get-AzureRmMetric though.

Comment: @Jenny Sorry, I still can't use PowerShell to get this data like your script, I will test it tomorrow. By the way, we can find the data in Azure storage account-->table, as a workaround, we can use PowerShell to get data from storage account table:)

Comment: @Jenny You are right, same PowerShell command run on different versions get different results.  I have tested it with PowerShell version 3.4.0, it works fine. Because of Azure PowerShell use API too, new version PowerShell use different API, so we will get a different result.