# Automate the VM/Server resources alerts hosted on Azure cloud

Tags: powershell, azure

Is there any way script to automate the VM/Server resources alerts such as CPU, Memory, DiskSpace Utilization etc., hosted on Azure cloud. Like a powershell script which can give all these details?
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Do you mean you want to use PowerShell script to monitor it? how about Azure [metric alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-alerts-portal)?

Comment: yes,i need a powershell script to monitor / to get metric values..

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, maybe we can use this command `Get-AzureRmMetric` to get metric values.

We can use this script to get the metrics:

```
Get-AzureRmMetric -ResourceId $id -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -DetailedOutput -MetricNames "Network in"
```

Here is my PowerShell output:
[image]

Here are the metrics for Azure VM:

```
PS D:\testdata> (Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition -ResourceId $id).name

Value                     LocalizedValue
-----                     --------------
Percentage CPU            Percentage CPU
Network In                Network In
Network Out               Network Out
Disk Read Bytes           Disk Read Bytes
Disk Write Bytes          Disk Write Bytes
Disk Read Operations/Sec  Disk Read Operations/Sec
Disk Write Operations/Sec Disk Write Operations/Sec
CPU Credits Remaining     CPU Credits Remaining
CPU Credits Consumed      CPU Credits Consumed
```

If your Azure PowerShell version is 3.4.0, we can use Powershell to get other metrics, like this `\Memory\Committed Bytes`
[image]

More information about it, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258409/unable-to-access-guest-metrics-using-get-azurermmetric/46274028#46274028).

Comment: Thanks Jason for the quick reply,This is what i need..
hope this works..!Will get back to you if i need anything..

Comment: @avinashmitta Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)